# Putting a link and image inside of a table from a database

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, hyperlink

I have a small dilemma that I am trying to figure out. I have connected to my databse and I am able to echo the data I want onto my page, so I know that it is working. However, what I am trying to do is put it in a table.

I had this to start off with:

```
echo "<td>".'<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $ad['Image'] ) . '" />'."</td>";
```

This worked, perfectly. But now I have links in my database which I wish to assign to the image and so I have this:

```
echo "<a href='".$ad['Link']."'>".'<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $ad['Image'] ) . '" />'."</a>";
```

This also works perfectly, however it is not in a table... I am not sure how to incorporate the "td" tags into it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I have tried a few different combinations of single and double quotation marks but to no working piece of code.

Thank you very much!

Comment: why not try to put it inside a table? its just a matter of trying it first right?

Comment: This is where learning the basics of HTML in order to complement SQL comes in handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do it like this Add the `<td>` tag around for your second link

```
echo "<td>"."<a href='".$ad['Link']."'>".'<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $ad['Image'] ) . '" />'."</a>"."</td>";
```

Comment: Wow, I have been staring myself blind I think. I can't believe I missed that entirely. Thank you so much! It's just been one of those days I reckon! Hahaha. Thank you again, it's much appreciated.